# What's the relationship between <Provider> and connect() in React-Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm brand new to Redux and I'm trying to figure out the relationship between [`<Provider>`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#provider-store) and [`connect()`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options).

As I understand it, `connect` *connects* your component to the store. However, nowhere in the function arguments do you tell `connect` where exactly that store is!

If I'm not mistaken, the store is automagically provided to `connect()` by the `<Provider>`. This to me seems very counter-intuitive, because the [entire point](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/Motivation.html) of Redux is to be transparent.

So my question is, how does `<Provider>` pass the store off to `connect()` without using some sort of global variable? Does it traverse the entire tree, searching for `connect`ed components and then inject itself? Is that not inefficient? And if so, how would I use two different stores within the same component tree?

Secondly, supposing I don't want to use `<Provider>`, how can I use `connect()` without it? i.e., how can I explicitly pass a store to each connected component?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<Provider>` and `connect` are part of the `react-redux` module. They work together, you shouldn't really use one without the other. You *can* use `redux` on its own without `react-redux`, but you'll probably end up re-creating some or all of the features that `react-redux` provides.

`react-redux` works by using the [React context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html). Context is like a hidden layer for passing variables that are shared by multiple components without explicitly passing them. To use context, you need to set the context somewhere, but also, any component that wants to use something from the `context` needs to get the variable. In `react-redux` `<Provider>` essentially saves the store to the `context` and `connect` provides a way to get the store from the `context`.

If you haven't already, I [recommend these videos](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux) for getting started with Redux and `react-redux` from the creator of Redux.

Answer (score 4):

The [redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#passing-the-store) are pretty great and have some information regarding `Provider` and `connect()`

> The option we recommend is to use a special React Redux component
>   called `<Provider>` to magically make the store available to all
>   container components in the application without passing it explicitly.
>   You only need to use it once when you render the root component

Essentially it leverages the use of `context` which is from [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html). As per the docs this allows you to pass data through the component tree without having to pass the props down manually at every level.

There's no reason why you can't explicitly pass the store. The idea here is that it just makes things easier.

Comment: Yeah... it's the "magically" part I don't like. But "leverages `context`" adds some clarity, so thank you for that :)

Comment: Cool; If this answered your question please mark it as the answer. @mpen